# Login with FOSUserBundle

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony

I am using login with fosuserBundle in my Symfony application.But, login does not work and my application does not display any messages. May be error in `security.login.submit`.

This is my login.html.twig:

```
  {% extends "FOSUserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

   {% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

   {% block fos_user_content %}
   {% if error %}
 <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
 {% endif %}

        <div class="login-container">

          <div class="space-6"></div>

          <div class="position-relative">
            <div id="login-box" class="login-box visible widget-box no-border">
              <div class="widget-body">
                <div class="widget-main">
                <form method="post" action={{path("fos_user_security_check") }}">

                      <label class="block clearfix">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">

                          <input type="text" name="_username" class="form-control" value="{{ last_username }}" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}" required="required" />
                          <i class="ace-icon fa fa-user"></i>
                        </span>
                      </label>

                      <label class="block clearfix">
                        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">

                          <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}" required="required" />
                          <i class="ace-icon fa fa-lock"></i>
                        </span>
                      </label>

                      <div class="space"></div>

                      <div class="clearfix">
                        <label class="inline">
                          <input type="checkbox" class="ace" name="_remember_me" value="{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}"/>

                          <span class="lbl"> Remember Me</span>
                        </label>

                        <button type="button" class="width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                          <i class="ace-icon fa fa-key"></i>
                          <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
                            {{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}

                        </button>

                      </div>
                  </form>
                     </div><!-- /.widget-main -->
                       </div><!-- /.widget-body -->
            </div><!-- /.forgot-box -->


          </div><!-- /.position-relative -->


        </div>

        {% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<button type="button"
```

To

```
<button type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit"
```

And remove `value="{{ last_username }}"` from:

```
<input type="text" name="_username" class="form-control" value="{{ last_username }}"
```